# Dark Overlay on hover to every OTHER element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Now I'm trying to add a dark overlay on hover to these elements. Its doing it job, however its covering the hovered state image as well. Also it wont revert back because the overlay div covers the entire container. The desired effect would be to have every element covered with an overlay, with the exception to the expanded one.

https://codepen.io/SteveGWR/pen/NaZJyp

```
<div class="container">

<ul class="grid-list">
  <li class="bath">
    <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Bath</div>
      <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
      <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bath ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="bristol">
    <div class="destination-title">Bristol</div>
      <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
      <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bristol ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="cardiff">
    <div class="destination-title">Cardiff</div>
      <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
      <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cardiff ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="cornwall">
    <div class="destination-title">Cornwall</div>
    <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
    <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cornwall ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>  

<!-- row 2 -->

<ul class="grid-list">
  <li class="dorset">
    <div class="destination-title">Dorset</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Dorset ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>



  <li class="Cotswolds">
    <div class="destination-title">Cotswolds</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cotswolds ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="Exeter">
    <div class="destination-title">Exeter</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Exeter ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>


  <li class="London">
    <div class="destination-title">London</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>London ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>  

</ul>
```

Comment: Don't add the overlay to each `li` but to the list's parent container and make sure that the hovered `li` has a higher `z-index` than the overlay, which itself should have a higher one than all the other `li`s.

Comment: @Connum  I have updated my pen. Added the hover to the .container class instead of li. But some work like hover 'london' for example, but the others are blocking the overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Update Your code like this 
    <style>
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


.grid-list{
width:100%;
float:left;
}
.grid-list li{
    width:25%;
float:left;
position:relative;
height:200px;
}
.grid-list li .dark-cover{ display:none; position:absolute; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); width:100%; height:100%; left:0px; top:0px;  }
.container:hover .dark-cover{ display:block;}

.container {

    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -475px;
/*    background: #FF4346;*/
        max-width: 950px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    height: 748px;


}

.grid-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 190px;
}
.grid-list li {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;

}

.destination-copy {
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  transition:1s all;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.cta-bath {
       display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s all;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    right: 110px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #013A04;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #0a493e;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 15px;
    /* line-height: normal; */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;

}


.promo-content {

     display:none;
  opacity:0;
  transition:1s all;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  width:300px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;

}


.promo-content h3 {
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;

}




.grid-list li:hover .destination-copy {
  animation: 1s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
  display:block;
}



.grid-list li:hover .cta-bath {
  animation: 1.7s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
  display:block;
}


.grid-list li:hover .promo-content {
  animation: 2.7s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
  display:block;
}

@keyframes fadein{
    0% { opacity:0; }
    66% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

.grid-list li {
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 25%; /*CHANGE*/

    /* min-width: 237px; */
    /* margin: 1em; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    list-style: none;
}

.grid-list li:hover {
  width:75%;
  height:158%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.destination-title {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:80px;
  right:0px;
  background-color:#054940;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:6px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Background images */
.bath {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/350);  
}
.bath:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/350);

}

.bristol {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/355);
}
.bristol:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/355);
}

.cardiff {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/356);
}
.cardiff:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/356);
}

.cornwall {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/357);
    clear: right;
}
.cornwall:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/357);
}

.dorset {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/359);

}
.dorset:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/359);
}


.Cotswolds {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/365);

}
.Cotswolds:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/365);
}


.Exeter {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/366);

}
.Exeter:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/366);
}


.London {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/367);

}
.London:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/367);
}

.overlay-in .dark-cover{ display:none!important; }

    </style>



    <div class="container">

<ul class="grid-list">

  <li class="bath">
     <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Bath</div>
      <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
      <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bath ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="bristol">
     <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Bristol</div>
      <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
      <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bristol ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="cardiff">
     <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Cardiff</div>
      <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
      <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cardiff ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="cornwall">
     <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Cornwall</div>
    <a href="#"><div class="cta-bath">Click Here</div></a>
    <div class="promo-content"><h3>Promo Content</h3><br/>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cornwall ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>  

<!-- row 2 -->

<ul class="grid-list">
  <li class="dorset">
  <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Dorset</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Dorset ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>



  <li class="Cotswolds">
  <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Cotswolds</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cotswolds ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>

  <li class="Exeter">
  <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">Exeter</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Exeter ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>


  <li class="London">
  <div class="dark-cover"></div>
    <div class="destination-title">London</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>London ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>  

</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
        jQuery("li").mouseover(function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass("overlay-in");
        });
        jQuery("li").mouseleave(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass("overlay-in");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what are you trying to do is to change the style of other elements when you are hover one element.

You can use some jQuery for this. Something like:

```
  $('.grid-list li').on('hover', function(){
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass('darker');
});
```

Let me know if that is what are you looking for.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Should 'darker' be the class I made called ".dark-cover" ?